# Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0*0) error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

i am getting the error:

> 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0*0)

I am new to coding and i am following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fv-A8lKn7VY

The code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class SwiftCoreDataHelper: NSObject {

    class func directoryForDatabaseFilename()->NSString{
        return NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingString("/Library/Private Documents")
    }

    class func databaseFilename()->NSString{
        return "database.sqlite";
    }

    class func managedObjectContext()->NSManagedObjectContext{


        do { try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(SwiftCoreDataHelper.directoryForDatabaseFilename() as String, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil) }
        catch {
            print("Error Creating Directory for DB")
        }
        //        NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(SwiftCoreDataHelper.directoryForDatabaseFilename(), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: &error)

        let path:NSString = "\(SwiftCoreDataHelper.directoryForDatabaseFilename()) + \(SwiftCoreDataHelper.databaseFilename())"

        let url:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path as String)

        let managedModel:NSManagedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles(nil)!

        let storeCoordinator:NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedModel)

        do {
       try storeCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
        }
        catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            }

        let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.MainQueueConcurrencyType)

        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = storeCoordinator

        return managedObjectContext      
    }

    class func insertManagedObject(className:NSString, managedObjectConect:NSManagedObjectContext)->AnyObject{

        let managedObject:NSManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(className as String, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectConect) as NSManagedObject

        return managedObject

    }

    class func saveManagedObjectContext(managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext)->Bool{
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
            return true
        } catch _ {
            return false
        }
    }    

    class func fetchEntities(className:NSString, withPredicate predicate:NSPredicate?, managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext)->NSArray{
        let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        let entetyDescription:NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(className as String, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)!

        fetchRequest.entity = entetyDescription
        if (predicate != nil){
            fetchRequest.predicate = predicate!
        }

        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        var items = NSArray()
        do { items = try managedObjectContext .executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            print("Fetch Request Failed")
        }
        return items
    }   
}
```

The code where error is generated is:

```
let entetyDescription:NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(className as String, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)!
```

I am unable to rectify the error.

Comment: I strongly would avoid those tutorials which suggest Foundation types (`NSString`, `NSDictionary`) rather than Swift native types (`String`, `Dictionary`) and `NSHomeDictionary()` rather than `URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:` of `NSFileManager` to specify directories in the application container.

Comment: Using methods on `NSBundle` to get directory locations is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`entityForName` returns an optional value. It probably crashed because you force-unwrap the result of this operation with `!`

You could use **optional binding** in this case to test if `entityForName` actually returns a value:

```
if let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(className as String, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) {
    // work with entityDescription
} else {
   // handle the case in which entityForName returns nil
}
```

Comment: yes i forcefully put ! at the end of  `let entetyDescription:NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(className as String, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) ` because it shows that the value of optional type NSEntityDescription? not unwrapped and it pops up a fix up  with !

Comment: Yes, the compiler sees an error pre-runtime and suggest an instant solution. Unfortunately, those solutions aren't always expedient – like in this case.

Comment: yes, could you please suggest me a solution for this error please? I am unable to resolve it

Comment: What do you mean? I think I already suggested a solution with my answer.

Comment: oh m so sorry, i meant that when i use the solution suggested by you it shows an error in the code below it i.e. **use of unresolved indentifier 'entetyDescription'** in                                                           `fetchRequest.entity = entetyDescription
        if (predicate != nil){
            fetchRequest.predicate = predicate!
        }`

Comment: I think you need to go back to Start with Swift and programming in general – seems like there's a lot of basics you need to cover before digging deeper into this.

Comment: I know it's some time later, but for anyone else coming here, to match the OP's code, this solution should say `if let entetyDescription = ...` instead of `if let entityDescription = ...` - the OP spelled "entity" as "entety" in their own variable names, causing the *use of unresolved identifier 'entetyDescription'* message in their following code when they, apparently, copy/pasted the solution into their code.